# Convert complecated class object to readable JSON format

Tags: python, json, nested

I have difficult and nested classes. 
For example I have something like that:

```
class class1:
    a = class2()
class class2:
    b = class3()
class class3:
    c = 5
```

How can I convert class1 object to readable JSON format? I don't want to overwrite encoder. Maybe some simple way for solving this problem exists.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: JSON format which shows me all classes and their attributes

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the help of my own Encoder Class and default function()